# unable to edit mongodb document in flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, jinja2, pymongo

I'm working on a project using flask and pymongo where I have a movies collection and  an instance of my movies collection is like :

```
movie = {"title":"Hobbit" , "year":"2013"}
```

I have an html jinja 2 page where I submit a form and I can change the title or the year of the movie . It is not required to change both of them .

My html template :

```
    <h1> Select a field in the movie to update  </h1>
    <form action = "{{url_for('execute_movie_update')}}" method = "post">
       <label="update-title">Change the title</label>
       <input type = "text" id="new-title" name = "new-title" >
       <label="update-year"> Change year of publish  </label>  
       <input type = "text" id = "new-year" name = "new-year"> 
       <label="update-plot"> Change plot of movie  </label>
       <input type = "text" id = "new-plot" name = "new-plot">
       <button type = "submit">Submit changes</button> 
    </form>
```

If I use my flask endpoint which I will include below to change both the title and the year of the movie I have in my session the update is succesful . However if I change only one field

```
(ex. if I change the title only the year I have is set to " " instead of being the orginal year )
```

I  have my flask endpoint here . It updates a specific movie I have stored in a session :

```
@app.route('/executemovieupdate' , methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def execute_movie_update():
    if 'Email' in session and 'User' in session:
        email = session['Email']
        user = session['User']
        if user == 'Admin':
            if 'Movie' in session and 'Movie_year' in session and 'Movie_plot' in session:
                movie = session['Movie']
                year = session['Movie_year']
                plot = session['Movie_plot']
                tainia = movies.find_one({'title':movie , "year":year}) #the movie that I want to update
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    new_title = request.form.get('new-title') #get the fields I submitted in html
                    new_year = request.form.get('new-year')

                    if new_title!=None: #if I submit only title year is set to " "
                        print("update the title")
                        movies.update_one({"title":movie , "year":year} , {"$set":{"title":new_title} } )
                        session['Movie'] = new_title
                        movie = session['Movie']
                        print(session)

                    if new_year != None: #if i submit both title and year the program works 
                        print("update the year")
                        movies.update_one({"title":movie , "year":year} , {"$set": {"year":new_year}}) 
                        session['Movie_year']=new_year
                        year = session['Movie_year']
                        print(session)

                  

  
                    return ''' movie has been updated '''
                                                                                                          
                else:
                    return render_template('movie-update.html' , movie = tainia)        
            else:
                return redirect(url_for('admin.html'))    
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login')) 
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I would appreciate your help in guiding me to solve this issue . Thank you in advance.

EDIT: It seems that the problem lies in my if statements as I always enter both of them even if an item is not submitted (ex. I did not submit a title )

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED :
by changing title if statement to : `if new_title:` and year statement to `if new_year:`